# How to change phpMyAdmin logo to my own logo?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Can any body tell me how to change the phpMyAdmin logo to my own logo? Is it possible?

Comment: if u are @localhost file must be in installation ..

Comment: Replace logo_left.png with your own image...?

Comment: where does it located..!??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to rewrite the *phpmyadmin* image and you can access *httpd.conf* file, follow the below method.

Append the following line of code to *httpd.conf*:

```
redirect /phpmyadmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png /mypath/mylog.png
```

then restart the web- server.

Or If you want replace the image, just find out the `phpmyadmin` directory.
In Ubuntu the configuration file */etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf* contains the location of the *phpmyadmin*:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Here the location is */usr/share/phpmyadmin*.
So the logo file is */usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png*